# C++ constructors and implicit string conversion

Tags: c++, string, function, class, implicit-conversion

In c++, I can write a class with a constructor that takes a `std::string` parameter. This will allow me to construct instances of this class from either `std::string` or `char *`, due to implicit conversions.

Is there ever a reason to have both a `std::string` constructor and a `char *` constructor?

```
class MyStringClass {
 public:
    MyStringClass( const std::string &str ); // char *'s could implicitly use this constructor
    MyStringClass( const char * str );       // would this ever be necessary?
};
```

This question also applies to function arguments.

```
void do_stuff_with_string( const std::string &str );
void do_stuff_with_string( const char * str );
```

Edit:

To clarify, I am wondering more about the performance. Say these constructors/functions are calling into api's that only take `char *`. Is it worth it to have the two separate functions to avoid constructing a `std::string` if I don't have to?

```
void do_stuff_with_string( const std::string &str )
{
    do_stuff_with_string( str.c_str() );
}

void do_stuff_with_string( const char * str )
{
    // call some api that only accepts char *
}
```

Comment: The obvious reason is if you wanted to handle them differently. There are, of course, other reasons, which makes it difficult to answer this question without simply providing a list. Can you give us more information on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @CodyGray I guess I'm more asking along the lines of performance. Is it ever worth having both to avoid constructing a string (if inside the function I only use the .c_str() method, as an example), or is the overhead so minute I shouldn't worry about it?

Comment: @CodyGray As you point out yourself what you save is the construction of a string. Whether that overhead is "minute" depends on how the class is used in your program so difficult to answer here in general.

Comment: It's definitely a questionable design if you have a _const char*_ string, then create (via implicit conversion) a _const std::string&_ from it, and eventually pass it via _std::string::c_str()_ to some C-API with a _const char*_ interface. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to overload your constructors if you wished to handle a C-string and an `std::string` differently.

```
MyStringClass::MyStringClass( const std::string &str )
{
    // Do std::string-specific stuff here.
}

MyStringClass::MyStringClass(const char * str )
{
    // Do char* specific stuff here.
}
```

There's also the possibility that a parameter of `const char *` is not a null-terminated C-string, but in fact a pointer to a single character, or a non-null-terminated character array. In this case, an implicit conversion might fail.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int DoStuff(const std::string &myString)
{
    std::cout << myString << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    DoStuff("This is a null terminated c-string");  // Fine!

    char charArray[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };           // Not null terminated!
    DoStuff(charArray);                             // Uh oh!
}
```

The example above is for a function, but the same could be applied to a constructor too. The above example compiles without warnings!

In terms of performance, there is certainly a hit due to the fact that an `std::string(const char * const)` constructor will copy the c-string into it's own internal buffer. However in most cases the impact will be negligible since the copy is extremely efficient. With very large strings however, it could be an issue.

As a general rule though, try to work with C++ strings as much as possible, and use the `std::string::c_str()` member when C-style strings are required. The occasional string copy from `char*` to `std::string` will be a micro-optimization in most cases. Only in very performance-critical code would this be a potential concern.

Comment: The last example is an `// Uh oh!` no matter what. Since you don't pass in the length of the array as a parameter, you'll read right off the end. The only way for the function to know it is to locate a sentinel character. And then you've just re-invented C-style strings.

Comment: @CodyGray - Technically correct (the best kind of correct)! My point was that a `char *` doesn't necessarily have to be a c-string, and in those cases overloads would be necessary, and in the latter case a length parameter would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, suppose you want to free the memory held by the `char *` string from the constructor. In that case you'd need two different constructors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a C API that requires *(const) char** function arguments, you usually (also) want to provide a *(const) char** C-style interface.

For instance, think of a RAII wrapper *Iconv* for iconv(3). In *Iconv's* initialization you will need to wrap

```
iconv_t iconv_open(const char* tocode, const char* fromcode);
```

Do you really want *Iconv's* (only) constructor to be

```
Iconv(const std::string& tocode, const std::string& fromcode);
```

especially if your arguments (tocode, fromcode) most likely come from the command line (argv)?

In this case, I would define the corresponding C-style constructor, and possibly also the preceding one for convenience (which then calls the C-style constructor via std::string::c_str()).